# Please explain this asymptotic equation

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

From Valdimir A.Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I, pp. 144-145,
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{\alpha}&=1+\frac{\alpha}{1!} x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!} x^2+ \dotsb+ \\
&\phantom{={}}+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsb(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}x^n+O(x^{n+1})\quad\text{as }x\to 0
\end{align}
Example 44, as $x\to\infty$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{x^3+x}{1+x^3}&=\frac{1+x^{-2}}{1+x^{-3}} = \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x^2} \right)\left(1+ \frac{1}{x^3} \right)^{-1} \\
& = \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x^2} \right) \left(1- \frac{1}{x^3} +O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)\right) = \left(1+ \frac{1}{x^2} +O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right) 
\end{align} 
I don’t understand this equation (left to right side)
\begin{align}
\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x^2} \right) \left(1- \frac{1}{x^3} +O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)\right) = \left(1+ \frac{1}{x^2} +O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)
\end{align} 
Please explain it, thanks.

Comment: mathisbeauty.$ (1+1/x^2)(1-1/x^3+O(1/x^6))=(1-1/x^3+O(1/x^6)+1/x^2-1/x^5+O(1/x^8))=(1+1/x^2+O(1/x^3))$ these are terms of lowest order .

Comment: @PeterSzilas  By the rule $O(f(x))/g(x)=O(f(x)/g(x))$, I got it, thank you very much!

Comment: mathisbeauty.A pleasure. Is is the distributive law, and expressions like $(1/x^2)O(1/x^6)=O(1/x^8).$

Comment: @PeterSzilas $$\begin{align} & \quad 1+\frac{1}{x^2} + \left[ O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right) + O\left(\frac{1}{x^8}\right) -\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^5}\right]  \\&= 1+\frac{1}{x^2} +\left[O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)-1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right] \frac{1}{x^3} \\ &=1+\frac{1}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\end{align}$$ is it right?

Comment: Is fine. You can skip second line, just go from your first to your last line, keeping terms of 'lowest order'.Ok?

Comment: @PeterSzilas Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply out:

$\begin{align*}
  &\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x^2} \right)
      \left(
          1
             - \frac{1}{x^3}
             + O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)
      \right) \\
   &\qquad=
          \left(
             1
                 + \frac{1}{x^2}
                 - \frac{1}{x^3}
                 - \frac{1}{x^5}
                + \frac{1}{x^2}
                       O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)
      \right) \\
  &\qquad=
          \left(
             1
                 + \frac{1}{x^2}
                 - \frac{1}{x^3}
                 - \frac{1}{x^5}
                + O\left(\frac{1}{x^8}\right)
      \right) \\
  &\qquad=
          \left(
             1
                 + \frac{1}{x^2}
                 + O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)
           \right)
\end{align*}$

Last step throws away some precision by cutting off after the second term.